# Possible to choose table with a wildcard?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Using **AdventureWorks2012**, I want to select all tables of Production, can I do this using a *wildcard like Prod%?*

**EDIT:** Was trying to choose table with wildcard like this:

```
WHERE t.name in ('Sales%')
```

In hope of getting all tables starting with "`Sales.`", but didn't work.

However using:

```
WHERE LIKE 'Sales%'
```

selects all tables that starts with Sales in the "`second step`", ie, `Sales.SalesCustomer`.

What I want to do:

```
select all "Sales.***"
```

Hope this makes more sense

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: I posted answer this query will return you list od tables with wild card and then if you want you can dynamic query to select each of them if this is wt u want .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Here you can find all table where table name start with temp hope it helps 

 select t.name,s.name as  schemaname from sys.tables t
   join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
   where 
  t.name like '%sales%'     and 
  s.name='sales'
```

Comment: this query will return you list od tables with wild card and then if you want you can dynamic query to select each of them if this is wt u want

Comment: Using LIKE 'Sales%' I am able to get all tables starting with Sales, however, if you're familiar with AdventureWorks2012 the tables are named as follows, for instance, Sales.CountryRegionCurrency, and so on. I want all of these starting with "Sales." to be chosen, however SQL disregards the first "Sales."

Comment: is Sales is schema ?

Comment: Updated my answer now you can use schema name in filter as well  . this query retuned be 9 records when I run on AdventureWorks2012 . I hope this is what you are looking for .

Comment: Nice to hear that . I hope you find it useful